# Display Blob Image from MySQL to Django Template

Tags: python, html, django, base64

I have models.py like this

```
class p2_qc_ed(models.Model):
    qc_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='app_one/me/qc/ed/', null=True, blank=True)`
```

my views to upload the image like this

```
captured_image_data  = request.POST.get('capturedImageInput')
format,captured_image_data = captured_image_data.split(';base64,') 
ext = format.split('/')[-1] 
data = ContentFile(base64.b64decode(captured_image_data), name='temp.' + ext)             
qc_entry  = p2_qc_ed(qc_image=data)
qc_entry.save()
```

while form submission, capturedImageInput value was like

**"data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAoAAAAHgCAYAAAA10dzkAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAIABJREFUeF7svQ2P9Lp2nSlVvec/DxBkcufGztiZTOIYGRs2gnsB/0y/XdJgk2IVq1rci8UltqTu..."**

the image uploaded successfully and I can see the image in **'app_one/me/qc/ed/'** folder.

But when i try to retrieve the image i use the following snippet

```
`def ed_test(request):`
`    image_data = p2_qc_ed.objects.get(id=444).qc_image`
`    encoded_image_data = base64.b64encode(image_data).decode('utf-8')    `
`    print(image_data,encoded_image_data)`
`    return        
    render(request,'qc_checksheet/qc_ed_test.html','encoded_image_data':encoded_image_data})`
```

here the printed values are **b'app_one/me/qc/ed/temp.png'** **'YXBwX29uZS9tZS9xYy9lZF9zYW5kaW5nL3RlbXAucG5n'**

but I cannot display it in
 `<img src="data:image/png;base64,{{encoded_image_data}}">`

django template.

can someone help me what is wrong with this ? Thanks in advance.

expected to display the uploaded image but i couldn't .

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.